# angularjs http post bad request 400

Tags: angularjs, http, post

I am sending a post request with `$http`:

```
$http({
    method: 'Post',
    url: urlBuilt,        
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},                                                         
    params: {"colCode":modCodeCol,"whereClause":clause}
});
```

When the where clause is very huge, I am getting bad request `400 error`. When the where clause contains a small string it works. How can we fix this.

Comment: coud you share an example of data to `whereClause` ???

Answer (score 1):

Try change **params** to **data** in the block of **http** like this.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: urlBuilt,        
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},                                                         
    data:{"colCode":modCodeCol,"whereClause":clause}
});
```

**params** if for **queryParams** it mean it send on the url.
**data** appends to the request body.

Comment: @Carrasco, I used data, and in my spring contoller I have changed requestParam to requestBody like below,the request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Answer (score 0):

for POST request you need to send data as JSON also it's better to Get a promise and resolve it after send the request like this :

```
  var data = {
               "colCode":modCodeCol,
               "whereClause":clause 
             }
  $http({ url: urlBuilt , method: 'POST', data: data })
        .then(function (result) {
            deferred.resolve({ data: result.data.Data, count: result.data.Count });

        });
```

Comment: I just want to know why need use $q in here? And you can use short syntax of http . `$http.post(urlBuld,data).then(...)`

Comment: no one used $q anywhere here! $q used when you want have bulk requests